# WFFM 8.0 - Save to Database action missing

Tags: database, save, sitecore, action, web-forms-for-marketers

I have just installed Web Forms For Marketers 8.0 and do a test form. Trying to select `Save to Database` from the list of action but it is not there. Also, I have checked `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions` but it is not there as well.

Why did they remove saving to database? How do I return it back again (as that is a requirement on my existing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not worry about, saving to SQL database is still there.

What happened is that Sitecore have removed **Save to Database** action definition item, but not the functionality itself, so as soon as you have restored WFFM database and set up correct connection string - that will work for you.

Please note that config has changed, now there are 3 config files:

```
Sitecore.Forms.config
Sitecore.Forms.MVC.config
Sitecore.Forms.Xtune.CD.config
```

The first one has a setting that sets name of connection string, like below:

```
<setting name="WFM.ConnectionString" value="wfm" />
```

So now you store you forms connection string along with the rest of connection strings in the **Include\ConnectionStrings.config** file.

Here is [an article](http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/web-forms-for-marketers-8-0-how-to-save-to-database) about WFFM 8.0 and **Remark 4** from there answers exactly what you've asked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Web Forms For Marketers for Sitecore 8 work in a slightly different way comparing to older versions of WFFM.

Now, every time user fills a form, when session of this user expires, form data is stored in Mongo and then it's processed into SQL Server reporting database (see the script inside WFFM package to see what tables are created).

You can see the WFFM reports from Sitecore Desktop, Sitecore Content Editor and other places where you have links to the reports.

I know that some people don't like the new version of reports. You can easily reuse [Web Forms for Marketers 2.5 - SQL PROVIDER (SaveToDatabase)](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Web_Forms_for_Marketers_SQL_SaveToDatabase.aspx) module if you need other ways of reporting - you just need to download sources, fix some namespaces, add restore `wfm` database from the older version of WFFM.